# Including PDO database connection in class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been trying to figure out the best way to include my PDO database connection in my classes. Here is the code i have so far and won't work.

```
class Delete {

private $connection;
    function __construct() {
        $this->open_connection();
    }
    public function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(localhost, 1, 1);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db(1, $this->connection);
            if (!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }

public function delete_file($deletelink) {

$dbh = $this->connection;



$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT hash FROM files WHERE delete_link = :delete_link");
//PARAM_INT for int, PARAM_STR for string, PARAM_BOOL for bool
$sth->bindParam(':delete_link', $deletedlink, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
$countrows = $sth->rowCount();
 if ($countrows == 0) {
return false;   
 } else {



$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT filename, hash, ext FROM files WHERE delete_link = :delete_link");
//PARAM_INT for int, PARAM_STR for string, PARAM_BOOL for bool
$sth->bindParam(':delete_link', $deletedlink, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();

}
```

}

If anyone has a better way of doing it, please share =) Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you going to create a PDO connection in the every class you're using?!

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: -1 Because, you only say "won't work" without saying why.  You also don't seem keen to learn what you did wrong.  This question is like: I have this really dodgy attempt, plz give me teh codez.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing procedural mysql_* functions with PDO. Why don't you setup the PDO-object and assign it to the object through a setter-method/constructor?

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn);
$delete = new Delete($pdo);
$delete->deleteFile($filename);

// ..
class Delete {
  protected $_pdo;
  public function __construct(PDO $pdo) { $this->_pdo = $pdo; }
  public function deleteFile($filename) { $this->_pdo->query(".."); /* .. */ }
}
```

Please consider changing your class' name, its too common (delete what? where? how?)

Comment: So should i keep my PDO connection in another page? How do i get the object $dbh into my functions? Also, in your example, where does the connection information go? Can i not using my current PDO queries with it?

Answer (score 0):

I use a very simple class what does exactly that, using a static connection:

source:
http://simple_pdo_implementation.onlinephpfunctions.com

```
<?php
class sql
{
public static $db = false;
private $database_host = '127.0.0.1';
private $database_user = 'username';
private $database_pass = 'verySecretPassWord';
private $database_db = 'database';

function __construct()
{
    if (self::$db === false) {
        $this->connect();
    }
    return self::$db;
}

private function connect()
{
    $dsn = $this->database_type . ":dbname=" . $this->database_db . ";host=" . $this->database_host;
    try {
        self::$db = new PDO($dsn, $this->database_user, $this->database_pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
        self::$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        //Comment this out on a production environment
        //print_r($e->errorInfo);
        //echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

}
```